# Sklearn f-beta score implementation problems

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, random-forest

I have a problem with the performances of a Random Forest Classifier after the hyper-parameters optimization, apparently the scorer I'm using does the opposite thing I want it to do. Can you help me in figuring out where is the mistake? Here the details.

I'm using scikit-learn [`make_scorer()`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.make_scorer.html) function to implement a scorer that uses [`fbeta_score()`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.fbeta_score.html) with beta = 0.5 as score function:

```
fO5_scorer = make_scorer(fbeta_score, beta=0.5)
```

I use this scorer inside a 10-fold [cross-validation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html) procedure to find the best hyper-parameters of a Random Forest Classifier using a [randomized search](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.RandomizedSearchCV.html) over the parameters defined in the dictionary `param_dist` ('min_samples_leaf','min_samples_split','n_estimators', etc):

```
RF_clf = RandomForestClassifier(n_jobs=-1)
cv = cross_validation.KFold(len(X_train), n_folds=10)
random_search_f05 = RandomizedSearchCV(RF_clf, param_distributions=param_dist, scoring=fO5_scorer, n_iter = 50, cv=cv)
tuned_RF = random_search_f05.fit(X_train,y_train)
```

I then compute the confusion matrix to assess the performance of my model on the test set, since I'm dealing with a binary classification problem this is a 2x2 matrix:

```
[[ 1109   114]
[  557 13266]]
```

Since my problem is highly imbalanced and [therefore the accuracy is always very high](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accuracy_paradox) I want to evaluate my model using [precision and recall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precision_and_recall), so from the confusion matrix I can compute that:

- model precision: 0.67
- model recall: 0.90

To understand if my hyper-parameters optimization improved my results I compare the performance of this Random Forest with the performance of another Random Forest with default parameters:

```
[[  826   397]
 [  154 13669]]
```

- model with non optimized parameters precision: 0.84
- model with non optimized parameters recall: 0.68

I can see that the recall of the model with optimized hyper-parameters has increased its recall and decreased its precision.

The problem is that since I defined the scorer using a f-0.5 measure I was expecting the opposite behavior! In fact, also according to the [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.fbeta_score.html):

> The beta parameter determines the weight of precision in the combined score. beta < 1 lends more weight to precision, while beta > 1 favors recall (beta -> 0 considers only precision, beta -> inf only recall).

So since I've set my beta to 0.5 I should have precision increased. This seems to be true also according to [wikipedia definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F1_score#cite_note-2):

> The F-measure was derived so that F-β "measures the effectiveness of retrieval with respect to a user who attaches β times as much importance to recall as precision"

So why do I have the opposite result? Have I defined in the wrong way my scorer?

---

EDIT:

to evaluate the confusion matrix and precision and recall I use the following:

```
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
from sklearn.metrics import recall_score
from sklearn.metrics import precision_score
```

and then for the model with "default" parameters:

```
y_pred_def = RF_default.predict(X_test)
cm_def = confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred_def,labels = [1,0])
```

and for the model with optimized hyper-parameters:

```
y_pred = tuned_RF.predict(X_test)
cm = confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred,labels = [1,0])
```

Comment: Please show how you have calculated the confusion matrix and recall and precision for both cases (hyperparameter optimized and default)

Comment: @VivekKumar I've added an edit, thank you for the comment

Comment: An alternative thing to try is to specify the class_weight parameter of the classifier and pass to this parameter a dictionary with a higher weight for the minority class  than for the majority class.